# RoR Rspec tags with have_selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

EDIT:  Figured it out. I should be doing `("span.age", :content => ...)`

I am getting the following error when I run this rspec test

```
response.should have_selector("span.age", :age => work1.age.to_s):

Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("span.age", :age => work1.age.to_s)
       expected following output to contain a

     <span.age age='15'/> tag
```

Output

```
....

     <td class="work">
       <span class="age">15</span><br><span class="content">B.1</span>
     </td>
```

Running the same test on the span.content tag with

```
response.should have_selector("span.content", :content => work1.content)
```

yields no mistakes. However, if I purposefully make a mistake in that tag, I get the same output but a different expectation:

```
     <span.content>B.1</span.content>
```

The only thing different between content and age is that age is an integer and content is a string. I am unsure why this is happening. Thanks for the help.

Oh, also, this doesnt happen in dev setting, only in test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, I believe, lies in your choice of the symbol ":content" for your second try.  To correct your original test, change it to 
     response.should have_selector("span.age", :content => work1.age.to_s)

This is because the key ":content" refers to the contents of the "span" element, so you are saying: "the response should have a "span.age" selector whose contents equals the result of evaluating the expression "work1.age.to_s".  Your original test was looking for a "span.age" element with the attribute "age"  equal to that.